# Can my AMD Radeon HD 6950 graphics card take a minidisplay port to displayport?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, displayport

So I've had my AMD Radeon HD 6950 for around 3 years now, and I've always had 2 DVI's connected to it.

I have decided that I would like to connect another monitor to it, without buying another card. It currently has 1 HDMI and 2 mini displayports in the back which are free.

I believe that I could purchase a mini displayport to displayport cable, and connect it to a monitor that has a displayport input.

From experience, I believe that Radeon graphic cards can take 2 legacy inputs and up to 4 displayport connections. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort should always work where a straight display port would work as far as I understand, since its the same signalling, just a different connector. Likewise an **active** display port to DVI/HDMI/VGA should always work where a plain display port would have.

Regarding multiple displays with AMD cards, Id take a look at: [How do I connect three or More Monitors to an AMD Radeon™ HD 5000, HD 6000, and HD 7000 Series Graphics Card?](http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/154) (AMD Support article).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

To be more exact, you have 2 ports for either DVI's or HDMI or any combination, and additionally you can have displayports connected.

So you cannot have 2 DVI and HDMI, but you can have 1 DVI and 1 HDMI or 2 DVI.

The amount of displayports can be any. The total displayports depends on the graphicscard, but is not limited by the DVI or HDMI ports used.